# How to find out the data size of a received udp packet

Tags: php, sockets, networking, udp

I developed a small udp server with `php`

```
<?php
$socket = stream_socket_server("udp://0.0.0.0:1201", $errno, $errstr, STREAM_SERVER_BIND);
if (!$socket) {
    die("$errstr ($errno)");
}

do {
    $pkt = stream_socket_recvfrom($socket, 1, 0, $peer);
    echo "$peer\n";
} while ($pkt !== false);

?>
```

I want to print the data size of each received packet and also the source port and the dest port.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a socket which was created for UDP, then the return value of the receive function is the size of the packet. I looked up some example code but then specifically for php :

```
do {
    $pkt = stream_socket_recvfrom($socket, 1, 0, $peer);
    echo "$peer\n";
    stream_socket_sendto($socket, date("D M j H:i:s Y\r\n"), 0, $peer);
} while ($pkt !== false);
```

this is as I expected : the return value of the receive function $pkt is the size of the packet received, whereas $peer is the content of what is received.

If you were to print the value of $pkt you would see that it contains the packet size.

Packet sizes on UDP do matter for the application. If you use UDP and you send 2050 bytes, if the packet does not get lost, you will exactly receive those 2050 bytes at the receiver. So there is no need and it is even not possible to access the UDP header in normal circumstances. No need to go to a raw socket either.
The packet sizes that can be sent by UDP are basically limited in size by IP. (64k) Because IP is going to fragment the packet during the send, and do the defragmentation on the receive side. fragments can be received out of order and the like. IP simply puts them back together.

To avoid confusion I am referring to the size of the packet that the user is sending and receiving as payload to UDP.

ref `string stream_socket_recvfrom ( resource $socket , int $length [, int $flags = 0 [, string &$address ]] )`
from http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-recvfrom.php

shows you can get the address of whoever is sending to you as well.

Comment: What if the message `$pkt` is fragmented across multiple UDP packets?

Comment: UDP is on top of IP. IP handles fragmentation, you always receive whole packets. It is mentioned in the answer. If the user needs message sizes bigger than 64K. Then he must device something up of his own on top of UDP in his application. TFTP uses 'smaller chunks to send big files

Comment: I mean the remote end may just send a single byte twice, you would receive two bytes at once while it were two udp packets.

Comment: if the remote sends a single byte twice over UDP the receiver will receive 2 single bytes as well. UDP is not TCP which is streaming. UDP is packet based.

Comment: I mean on application level, where your code operates on. You cannot rely that what socket_recv() returns is the data section of a single UDP paket. You may try these examples: http://www.binarytides.com/udp-socket-programming-in-php/ .. (Add the `sock_sendto()` call in server twice and see how it messes up things)

Comment: ^^^ play around a bit, don't give up too early.

Comment: I am afraid you are wrong. I am responsible for both UDP and TCP implementation at source level. It may sound a bit arrogant but I really know how it works from socket level up until it reaches the ethernet layer. UDP packets are never fragmented at UDP level, they are at IP level, UDP packets are never ever combined into one. Your experiments may have puzzled you a bit. Packets can get lost because UDP is best effort. It may have seemed like it messes things up. If you try with adding sequence numbers in the udp payload you can see that.

Comment: No issue, and probably you are right but I talk about the **application layer**. `sock_recvfrom` works on application layer. It could even work without UDP (if there would be some other datagram protocol). That's the OSI stack. You can't rely on properties of the underlying protocol, that's why you cannot rely on the fact that `socket_recv()` delivers data from one single udp packet. Especially in a high load environment, data might be accumulated from multiple udp packets. But hey, probably I'm missing something.

Comment: If you don't believe me read unix network programming the socket API from  Stevens. A reference book about the topic. or TCP/IP guide from kozierok http://www.amazon.com/The-TCP-Guide-Comprehensive-Illustrated/dp/159327047X

Comment: Sockets are application layer, but they never combine UDP packets together. What you describe can only happen for TCP. In case of high load, packets can be dropped. That is most likely what you see.

Comment: You told `packets will never get accumulated in a single recv_from call`. That's interesting. If you say so, I'll believe that this is an implementation detail of the socket api which I can rely on. I didn't know implementation details of that API. But would you say relying on that is a good programming style? (Since it defeats the principles of the OSI stack)

Comment: You can rely on that. Many network protocols based on UDP rely on that too. I don't see why it would defeat the OSI stack, maybe you can explain me why you think so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75182/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-philip-stuyck).

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work on udp level, meaning the udp communication itself will be handled by the kernel. You are working on application level, you just receive the data. If the data is fragmented across multiple upd pakets wouldn't notice that. This is by design in the OSI stack.

If you communicate on UDP level, you can get the size of each paket in the UDP header. You would need to use *raw sockets* for that. But I think this would be interesting only for educational purposes.

Normally application code does not care about the size of individual UDP pakets, but cares about the size of a *message*. The message format is defined in the upper layer application protocol. HTTP defines the `Content-Length` header for example.